# How to add Class on current li not on siblings Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a structure Like :

```
  <div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Option 1</li>
                <li>Option 2</li>
                <li>Option 3</li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Option 1</li>
                <li>Option 2</li>
                <li>Option 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Option 1</li>
                <li>Option 2</li>
                <li>Option 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <ul>
</div>
```

I need to add class active on element which is clicked not on siblings.
I am using

```
public select(item) {
    this.selectedLi = item;
  }
  public isActive(item) {
    return this.selectedLi === item; 
  }
```

But this will add class on all li not on current.

Is there any way to do that. Please Help.

Comment: Where is your select function called from?

Comment: It is something like we can choose different option from each Li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[ngClass]` to set class, then in `component` `this.selectedItem = newValue;` make that value `selected`

**HTML**

```
   <div>
    <ul>
         <li>
            <ul>
                <li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem.firstLi == 2}" (click)="listClick($event, 2, 'firstLi')">Option 1</li>
                <li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem.firstLi == 3}" (click)="listClick($event, 3, 'firstLi')">Option 2</li>
                <li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem.firstLi == 4}" (click)="listClick($event, 4, 'firstLi')">Option 3</li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem.secondLi == 6}" (click)="listClick($event, 6, 'secondLi')">Option 1</li>
                <li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem.secondLi == 7}" (click)="listClick($event, 7, 'secondLi')">Option 2</li>
                <li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem.secondLi == 8}" (click)="listClick($event, 8, 'secondLi')"> Option 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
selectedItem = {
  firstLi: '',
  secondLi: ''
}
listClick(event, newValue, value) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem[value] = newValue;  // don't forget to update the model here
    // ... do other stuff here ...
}
 }
```

[**Here is a WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgvjax?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks,
But In this case it will remove the active class from the other Li also. It is something like we can choose different option from each Li.

Comment: but you asked the same? `I need to add class active on element which is clicked not on siblings`

Comment: May be there is some communication gap but I need something that we can choose different option from different Li.

Comment: means, can you please elaborate?

Comment: you need multiple to be active?

Comment: Whatever we are doing on "this.selectedItem" it will add class active where it finds the option 1 in each Li. But what I need is that I can choose different Option from each Li Whatever I choose in first Li and I can choose different option in other Li also. Don't remove the active option from the other Li.

Comment: @AyoushKohli, please check now https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgvjax?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @AyoushKohli, have you checked that?

Comment: Thanks for the response. you have used the static values in "selectedItem" but the Li are dynamic I will make them dynamic as per your response.

will update you once I will do that.

Comment: @AyoushKohli, please check now I made it dynamic, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgvjax?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: you have used the static value like firstLi and secondLi in 
selectedItem = {
  firstLi: '',
  secondLi: ''
}
 and static value in "selectedItem.firstLi "
<li *ngFor="let list of firstList" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem.firstLi == list.value}" (click)="listClick($event, list.value, 'firstLi')">{{list.name}}</li>

This is the thing I need to make dynamic

Comment: those `li` lists are also dynamic?

Comment: As you have used 2 values in "selectedItem = { firstLi: '', secondLi: '' }" . What if have 100 Li? I need to make this thing dynamic.

Comment: yes, I removed now, please check this code, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgvjax?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks, This is what i am looking for.

Comment: Glad to help you, please upvote my answer if you find it useful. :-)

Comment: Can you please help. What I need is edited in the URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njy9yt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @AyoushKohli, please check now, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njy9yt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: sry, that was wrng url, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4xieyq?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

### In your html

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
     <li [class.active]="selectedLi=='o1'" (click)="select('o1')">Option 1</li>
     <li [class.active]="selectedLi=='o2'" (click)="select('o2')">Option 2</li>
     <li [class.active]="selectedLi=='o3'" (click)="select('o3')">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
......
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

### And in your component.ts

```
select(option:string){
 this.selectedLi=option;
}
```

This will only add the active class on your desired li-element when clicked.

Comment: But In this case it will add the active class to other Li also. It is something like we can choose different option from each Li.

Comment: It will not add the class, unless the specific option is selected. You pass in an option to the select, eg 'op1', then the li with `[class.active]="selectedLi=='op1'"`, will be the only li with the active class.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use [class] property with conditional operator to set class,like below 

<div>
 <ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
     <li [class]="(isActive('o1') === true )? ' active' : ''" (click)="select('o1')">Option 1</li>
     <li [class]="(isActive('o2') === true )? ' active' : ''" (click)="select('o2')">Option 2</li>
     <li [class]="(isActive('o3') === true )? ' active' : ''" (click)="select('o3')">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
......
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

//in your component section 

select(option:string){

    this.selectedLi=option;
}
public isActive(item) {
  if(this.selectedLi === item){
    return true;
  }
```